# Bazel Gazelle Error : no such package '@org_golang_x_tools//go/analysis/internal/facts': BUILD file not found in directory

Tags: go, bazel

I'm building a very simple go project with bazel + gazelle.

Following this rules : https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#running-gazelle-with-bazel .

```go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello")
    })

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

My WORKSPACE :

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_go",
    sha256 = "207fad3e6689135c5d8713e5a17ba9d1290238f47b9ba545b63d9303406209c6",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/v0.24.7/rules_go-v0.24.7.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/v0.24.7/rules_go-v0.24.7.tar.gz",
    ],
)

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_gazelle",
    sha256 = "b85f48fa105c4403326e9525ad2b2cc437babaa6e15a3fc0b1dbab0ab064bc7c",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/releases/download/v0.22.2/bazel-gazelle-v0.22.2.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/releases/download/v0.22.2/bazel-gazelle-v0.22.2.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:deps.bzl", "go_register_toolchains", "go_rules_dependencies")
load("@bazel_gazelle//:deps.bzl", "gazelle_dependencies")
load("//:deps.bzl", "go_dependencies")

# gazelle:repository_macro deps.bzl%go_dependencies
go_dependencies()

go_rules_dependencies()

go_register_toolchains()

gazelle_dependencies()
```

My BUILD

```
load("@bazel_gazelle//:def.bzl", "gazelle")

# gazelle:prefix github.com/myprojectXYZ/go-bazel
gazelle(name = "gazelle")
```

When i'm generating files with gazelle i have the following error:

```
bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos -from_file=go.mod -to_macro=deps.bzl%go_dependencies

...
...
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_ch/c341ee081eec158c6db2e8b32b60c79e/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/tools/builders/BUILD.bazel:48:10: no such package '@org_golang_x_tools//go/analysis/internal/facts': BUILD file not found in directory 'go/analysis/internal/facts' of external repository @org_golang_x_tools. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '@io_bazel_rules_go//go/tools/builders:nogo_srcs'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:gazelle' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

Quite new to SO, I had the same problem, solved it by loading gazelle after calling `go_rules_dependencies()`

The WORKSPACE file looks like that:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_go",
    sha256 = "6f111c57fd50baf5b8ee9d63024874dd2a014b069426156c55adbf6d3d22cb7b",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/v0.25.0/rules_go-v0.25.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/releases/download/v0.25.0/rules_go-v0.25.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)

http_archive(
    name = "bazel_gazelle",
    sha256 = "b85f48fa105c4403326e9525ad2b2cc437babaa6e15a3fc0b1dbab0ab064bc7c",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/releases/download/v0.22.2/bazel-gazelle-v0.22.2.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/releases/download/v0.22.2/bazel-gazelle-v0.22.2.tar.gz",
    ],
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:deps.bzl", "go_register_toolchains", "go_rules_dependencies")
go_rules_dependencies()

load("@bazel_gazelle//:deps.bzl", "gazelle_dependencies")
load("//:go_third_party.bzl", "go_deps")

# gazelle:repository_macro go_third_party.bzl%go_deps
go_deps()


go_register_toolchains(version = "1.15.5")

gazelle_dependencies()
```

And here's the github post that explain why it's happening, better than me not explaining it correctly: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/issues/561#issuecomment-506047843

Comment: where did you get go_third_party.bzl file? I am having same issue, but I cannot reproduce your example.